# WSO2: How to integrate APIM and IS in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am currently evaluating WSO2 IS for authentication for APIM. Basically, the APIM login, authentication and token generation should happen through WSO2 IS.

I have read through many documentation which are present in wso2 sites but could not getting through it.

I am using IS as version 5.7.0 and APIM as version 2.5.0

If some one could help me in getting the proper documentation link which has step by steps process, it could be of great support.

However, I have gone through the below links

Here's [link1] (https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0#)

and 
Here's [link2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.1

As updated earlier, now I have integrated IS with IAM but when I am trying to fetch the application subscription token from store, I am getting below error

ERROR - AbstractKeyManager Can not retrieve OAuth application for the given consumer key : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://localhost:9445/services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:381)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:456)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)

Can someone please check and let me know how this can be avoided. Do i have to update the Hostname anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Refer this doc - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager. It contains the steps to configure IS as Key manager for APIM

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Also, can we test it using embedded H2 database

Comment: I successfully integrated IAM with APIM but I m facing one issue now.

Comment: When I am trying to open the application option from Store :.. I am getting 500 error and page cannot be displayed.

Comment: yes the error:
ERROR - APIStoreHostObject Error while obtaining application data
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not retrieve OAuth application for the given consumer key : xxxxxxxx-x--x-x-xx